# Cannot read property 'publicPath' of undefined

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, webpack

I've inherited a fairly large MVC project that uses nodeJS in it's frontend, while I'm learning about the technologies used in the software, I'm currently stuck with it showing the following on startup

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'publicPath' of undefined
at createWebpackDevServer (D:\PROJECT01\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:9:43)
```

any help or general ideas of a likely cause would be greatly appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: Add your `code` generating this `Exception`. [Read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example][1] and edit your Question accordingly.  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: For anyone landing from Google, I ran into this because of a `module.exports` that returned a Promise. More info here: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/907#issuecomment-346496683